# JQuery search field for dropdown

Tags: jquery, search

I have a wordpress form using gravity forms and chained selects add on which display data from csv file as a dropdown fields. I just need to add search input field on top of each dropdown so user can search through the list of data. I also attached the JQuery code, could you please help me to add this feature in this code

```
( function( $ ) {

window.GFChainedSelects = function( formId, fieldId, hideInactive, alignment ) {

    var self = this;

    self.formId       = formId;
    self.fieldId      = fieldId;
    self.hideInactive = hideInactive;
    self.alignment    = alignment;

    var $field = $( '#field_' + self.formId + '_' + self.fieldId );

    self.$selects  = $field.find( 'select' );
    self.$complete = $field.find( '.gf_chain_complete' );

    self.isDoingConditionalLogic = false;

    self.init = function() {

        gform.addAction( 'gform_input_change', function( elem, formId, fieldId ) {
            if( self.$selects.index( elem ) != - 1 ) {
                var inputId = $( elem ).attr( 'name' ).split( '_' )[1]; // converts "input_4.1" to "4.1"
                self.populateNextChoices( inputId, elem.value, $( elem ) );
            }
        }, 9 );

        self.$selects.filter( function() {
            var $select = $( this );
            return $select.hasClass( 'gf_no_options' ) || $select.find( 'option' ).length <= 1;
        } ).toggleSelect( true, self.hideInactive );
            //.prop( 'disabled', true ).hide();

        /*var $lastSelect = self.$selects.last();
        self.toggleCompleted( $lastSelect.hasClass( 'gf_no_options' ) || $lastSelect.val() );*/

        gform.addFilter( 'gform_is_value_match', function( isMatch, formId, rule ) {
            return self.isValueMatch( isMatch, formId, rule );
        } );

    };

    self.populateNextChoices = function( inputId, selectedValue, $select ) {

        var nextInputId = self.getNextInputId( inputId ),
            $nextSelect = self.$selects.filter( '[name="input_' + nextInputId + '"]' );

        // if there is no $nextSelect, we're at the end of our chain
        if( $nextSelect.length <= 0 ) {
            self.resetSelects( $select, true );
            self.resizeSelects();
            return;
        } else {
            self.resetSelects( $select );
        }

        if( ! selectedValue ) {
            return;
        }

        if( self.hideInactive ) {

            var $currentSelect = $( '[name="input_' + inputId + '" ]' ),
                $spinner       = new gfAjaxSpinner( $currentSelect, gformChainedSelectData.spinner, 'display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;margin:-1px 0 0 6px;' );

        } else {

            var $loadingOption  = $( '<option value="">' + gformChainedSelectData.strings.loading + '...</option>' ),
                dotCount        = 2,
                loadingInterval = setInterval( function() {
                    $loadingOption.text( gformChainedSelectData.strings.loading + ( new Array( dotCount ).join( '.' ) )  );
                    dotCount = dotCount > 3 ? 0 : dotCount + 1;
                }, 250 );

            $loadingOption.prependTo( $nextSelect ).prop( 'selected', true );
            $nextSelect.css( { minWidth: $nextSelect.width() } );
            $loadingOption.text( gformChainedSelectData.strings.loading + '.' );

        }

        $.post( gformChainedSelectData.ajaxUrl, {
            action:   'gform_get_next_chained_select_choices',
            input_id: inputId,
            form_id:  self.formId,
            field_id: self.fieldId,
            value:    self.getChainedSelectsValue(),
            nonce:    gformChainedSelectData.nonce
        }, function( response ) {

            if( self.hideInactive ) {

                $spinner.destroy();

            } else {

                clearInterval( loadingInterval );
                $loadingOption.remove();

            }

            if( ! response ) {
                return;
            }

            var choices       = $.parseJSON( response ),
                optionsMarkup = '';

            $nextSelect.find( 'option:not(:first)' ).remove();

            if( choices.length <= 0 ) {

                self.resetSelects( $select, true );

            } else {

                var hasSelectedChoice = false;

                $.each( choices, function( i, choice ) {
                    var selected = choice.isSelected ? 'selected="selected"' : '';

                    if ( selected )  {
                        hasSelectedChoice = true;
                    }

                    optionsMarkup += '<option value="' + choice.value + '"' + selected + '>' + choice.text + '</option>';
                } );

                $nextSelect.show().append( optionsMarkup );

                // the placeholder will be selected by default, rather than removing it and re-adding, just force the noOptions option to be selected
                if( choices[0].noOptions ) {

                    var $noOption = $nextSelect.find( 'option:last-child' ).clone(),
                        $nextSelects = $nextSelect.parents( 'span' ).nextAll().find( 'select' );

                    $nextSelects.append( $noOption );

                    $nextSelects.add( $nextSelect )
                        .addClass( 'gf_no_options' )
                        .find( 'option:last-child' ).prop( 'selected', true );

                    //self.toggleCompleted( true );

                } else {
                    $nextSelect
                        .removeClass( 'gf_no_options' )
                        //.prop( 'disabled', false ).show();
                        .toggleSelect( false, self );

                    if ( hasSelectedChoice ) {
                        $nextSelect.change();
                    }
                }

            }

            self.resizeSelects();

        } );

    };

    self.getChainedSelectsValue = function() {

        var value = {};

        self.$selects.each( function() {
            var inputId = $( this ).attr( 'name' ).split( '_' )[1]; // converts "input_4.1" to "4.1"
            value[ inputId ] = $( this ).val();
        } );

        return value;
    };

    self.getNextInputId = function( currentInputId ) {

        var index     = parseInt( currentInputId.split( '.' )[1] ),
            nextIndex = index + 1;

        if( nextIndex % 10 == 0 ) {
            nextIndex++;
        }

        return parseInt( currentInputId ) + '.' + ( nextIndex );
    };

    self.resetSelects = function( $currentSelect, isComplete ) {

        var currentIndex = self.$selects.index( $currentSelect ),
            $nextSelects = self.$selects.filter( ':gt(' + currentIndex + ')' );

        $nextSelects
            .toggleSelect( true, self.hideInactive )
            .find( 'option:not(:first)' )
            .remove()
            .val( '' )
            .change();

    };

    self.resizeSelects = function() {

        if( self.alignment != 'vertical' ) {
            return;
        }

        // reset width so it will be determined by its contents
        self.$selects.width( 'auto' );

        var width = 0;

        self.$selects.each( function() {
            if( $( this ).width() > width ) {
                width = $( this ).width();
            }
        } );

        self.$selects.width( width + 'px' );

    };

    self.toggleCompleted = function( isComplete ) {
        if( isComplete ) {
            self.$complete.fadeIn();
        } else {
            self.$complete.fadeOut();
        }
    };

    self.isValueMatch = function( isMatch, formId, rule ) {

        if( rule.fieldId != self.fieldId || self.isDoingConditionalLogic ) {
            return isMatch;
        }

        self.isDoingConditionalLogic = true;

        rule = $.extend( {}, rule );

        var valueObj   = self.getChainedSelectsValue(),
            fieldValue = Object.keys( valueObj ).map( function( key ) { return valueObj[ key  ]; } ),
            ruleValue = rule.value.split( '/' );

        for( var i = 0; i < ruleValue.length; i++ ) {
            if( ruleValue[i] == '*' ) {
                ruleValue[i] = fieldValue[i];
            }
        }

        ruleValue  = ruleValue.join( '/' );
        fieldValue = fieldValue.join( '/' );

        isMatch = gf_matches_operation( ruleValue, fieldValue, rule.operator );

        self.isDoingConditionalLogic = false;

        return isMatch;
    };

    $.fn.toggleSelect = function( disabled, hideInactive ) {
        this.prop( 'disabled', disabled );
        if( typeof hideInactive != 'undefined' && hideInactive ) {
            if( disabled ) {
                this.hide();
            } else {
                this.show();
            }
        }
        return this;
    };

    self.init();

};

function gfAjaxSpinner( elem, imageSrc, inlineStyles ) {

    var imageSrc     = typeof imageSrc == 'undefined' ? '/images/ajax-loader.gif': imageSrc,
        inlineStyles = typeof inlineStyles != 'undefined' ? inlineStyles : '';

    this.elem = elem;
    this.image = '<img class="gfspinner" src="' + imageSrc + '" style="' + inlineStyles + '" />';

    this.init = function() {
        this.spinner = jQuery(this.image);
        jQuery( this.elem ).after(this.spinner);
        return this;
    };

    this.destroy = function() {
        jQuery( this.spinner ).remove();
    };

    return this.init();
}

} )( jQuery );
```

HTML:

```
<li id="field_1_129" class="gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_129_1"></label><div class="ginput_container horizontal medium gfield_chainedselect" id="input_1_129"><span id="input_1_129_1_container" class="">
                <select name="input_129.1" id="input_1_129_1" class="" onchange="gf_input_change( this, 1, 129 );"><option value="" selected="selected" class="gf_placeholder">Level</option><option value="Undergraduate">Undergraduate</option><option value="Postgraduate">Postgraduate</option><option value="Foundation">Foundation</option><option value="HND">HND</option><option value="HNC">HNC</option></select>
            </span><span id="input_1_129_2_container" class="">
                <select name="input_129.2" id="input_1_129_2" class="" onchange="gf_input_change( this, 1, 129 );" style="min-width: 260px;"><option value="" selected="selected" class="gf_placeholder">Subject</option><option value="Art">Art</option><option value="Biological Sciences">Biological Sciences</option><option value="Bioscience">Bioscience</option><option value="Business">Business</option><option value="Chemical Engineering">Chemical Engineering</option><option value="Civil Engineering">Civil Engineering</option><option value="Computer Science">Computer Science</option><option value="Construction">Construction</option><option value="Design">Design</option><option value="Electrical Engineering">Electrical Engineering</option><option value="Engineering">Engineering</option><option value="Film">Film</option><option value="Finance">Finance</option><option value="Forensic">Forensic</option><option value="Games">Games</option><option value="Healthcare">Healthcare</option><option value="Jewellery">Jewellery</option><option value="Law">Law</option><option value="Performing Arts">Performing Arts</option><option value="Photography">Photography</option><option value="Policing">Policing</option><option value="Product Design">Product Design</option><option value="Social Science">Social Science</option><option value="Sport">Sport</option></select>
            </span><span id="input_1_129_3_container" class="">
                <select name="input_129.3" id="input_1_129_3" class="" onchange="gf_input_change( this, 1, 129 );" style="min-width: 300px;"><option value="" selected="selected" class="gf_placeholder">University</option><option value="London South Bank University">London South Bank University</option></select>
            </span><span id="input_1_129_4_container" class="">
                <select name="input_129.4" id="input_1_129_4" class="" onchange="gf_input_change( this, 1, 129 );" disabled=""><option value="" selected="selected" class="gf_placeholder">Course</option></select>
            </span><span class="gf_chain_complete" style="display:none;">&nbsp;</span></div></li>
```

Comment: Too dirty. Will you be able to put it in a snippet that we could run?

Comment: sorry about that, because it is a add on code, I cannot run it in a snippet unfortunately

Comment: Hmm, how about at least the html output of the dropdown? So we could create a script for that markup.

Comment: I cleaned it up a little does it help? there is a line optionsMarkup += '<option value="' + choice.value + '"' + selected + '>' + choice.text + '</option>'; I need to add search box outside this loop

Comment: Which browser are you using? If you're using chrome,firefox, do inspect element on the dropdown, and update the question with the html.

Answer (score 1):

I created a script wherein it would add an input field on top of each select (there's no css though). Everytime the user modifies the value of the input field, it would filter the select tag after it.

Do run the snippet and copy the script to your code. Be sure to put it at the end of your scripts probably at the footer tag or at the end of the body tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ginput_container>span").each(function() {

    if ($(this).attr("id") != null) {

      // if id attribute is not null, do something
      if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf("container") > -1) {

        // if id has the word 'container' do something
        // add an input field
        $(this).prepend("<input class='filter-input' style='display:block;'/>");
      }
    }
  });
});

$(document).on("keyup", ".filter-input", function() {

  // store filter value
  var filterValue = $(this).val();

  $(this).parent().find("option").each(function() {

    // loop through the option fields inside the parent span
    if ($(this).html().toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue.toUpperCase()) > -1) {

      // show if filter is a substring
      $(this).show();
    } else {

      // else hide
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});

function gf_input_change() {
  // don't include this
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li id="field_1_129" class="gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible">

  <label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_129_1"></label>
  <div class="ginput_container horizontal medium gfield_chainedselect" id="input_1_129">

    <span id="input_1_129_1_container" class="">
      <select name="input_129.1" id="input_1_129_1" class="" onchange="gf_input_change( this, 1, 129 );">
        <option value="" selected="selected" class="gf_placeholder">Level</option>
        <option value="Undergraduate">Undergraduate</option>
        <option value="Postgraduate">Postgraduate</option>
        <option value="Foundation">Foundation</option>
        <option value="HND">HND</option>
        <option value="HNC">HNC</option>
      </select>
    </span>

    <span id="input_1_129_2_container" class="">
      <select name="input_129.2" id="input_1_129_2" class="" onchange="gf_input_change( this, 1, 129 );" style="min-width: 260px;">
        <option value="" selected="selected" class="gf_placeholder">Subject</option>
        <option value="Art">Art</option>
        <option value="Biological Sciences">Biological Sciences</option>
        <option value="Bioscience">Bioscience</option>
        <option value="Business">Business</option>
        <option value="Chemical Engineering">Chemical Engineering</option>
        <option value="Civil Engineering">Civil Engineering</option>
        <option value="Computer Science">Computer Science</option>
        <option value="Construction">Construction</option>
        <option value="Design">Design</option>
        <option value="Electrical Engineering">Electrical Engineering</option>
        <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
        <option value="Film">Film</option>
        <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
        <option value="Forensic">Forensic</option>
        <option value="Games">Games</option>
        <option value="Healthcare">Healthcare</option>
        <option value="Jewellery">Jewellery</option>
        <option value="Law">Law</option>
        <option value="Performing Arts">Performing Arts</option>
        <option value="Photography">Photography</option>
        <option value="Policing">Policing</option>
        <option value="Product Design">Product Design</option>
        <option value="Social Science">Social Science</option>
        <option value="Sport">Sport</option>
      </select>
    </span>

    <span id="input_1_129_3_container" class="">
      <select name="input_129.3" id="input_1_129_3" class="" onchange="gf_input_change( this, 1, 129 );" style="min-width: 300px;">
        <option value="" selected="selected" class="gf_placeholder">University</option>
        <option value="London South Bank University">London South Bank University</option>
      </select>
    </span>

    <span id="input_1_129_4_container" class="">
      <select name="input_129.4" id="input_1_129_4" class="" onchange="gf_input_change( this, 1, 129 );" disabled=""> 
        <option value="" selected="selected" class="gf_placeholder">Course</option>
      </select>
    </span>

    <span class="gf_chain_complete" style="display:none;">&nbsp;</span>

  </div>
</li>
```